# Human friendly bash auto-completion with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, sudo, bash-completion

My system is Manjaro Linux based on Arch Linux, I use bash and `bash-completion`.

It works perfectly when I type something as regular user (no `sudo`)

```
$ rfkill <TAB><TAB>
block    event    help     list     unblock
```

but when I type it with sudo

```
$ sudo rfkill <TAB><TAB>
Display all 3811 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Obviously, it tries to complete `sudo` command but I want it to complete `rfkill`.

I know I can change this behavior by editing `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo` file, but I have no idea how to say *if second word is not a flag for sudo then use completion for next word*.

Do you have?

**UPD:** I'm testing `Ubuntu 16.04` in virtual machine and I see it works as expected. I'll check the difference between ubuntu's `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo` file and mine, if any.

**UPD2**: There is some mirror (meaningless) difference between these files, anyway that didn't help. I have more ideas to test...

Comment: Are you sure you have removed `complete -cf sudo` in your `.bashrc` and your `.bash_profile` (this was my problem)? And are you sure you've sourced the completion file, i.e. `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` in your `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same problem (running Manjaro) and found a solution in the Manjaro Forum ([Source)](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-auto-complete-a-command-with-sudo-privilege/50263/25):

1. Make sure `bash-completion` is actually installed by checking whether `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exists. If not install it with `pacman -S bash-completion`
2. In your `~/.bashrc` file make sure that `complete -cf sudo` is commented out. Otherwise, this will make `sudo` only auto-complete filenames and commands but not use bash-completion.

I hope this helps you solving the problem

Comment: I couldn't figure out what file bash was sourcing that was calling `complete -cf sudo` so I used bash -x to see what files get sourced. I have seen several forums/comments/threads that say that you *want* the above line, but if bash-completion is installed correctly, this is definitely not what you want. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

use double tab:

```
sudo rfkill <TAB><TAB>
```

**UPD**

if there is not that line, add this to your `.bashrc`

```
complete -cf sudo
```

Comment: I mean I do use double tab, I'm going to edit my question, thanks

Comment: It doesn't work (actually I already had this line in `.bashrc`), I'll try to replace `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo` file tomorrow, have no time now.